# Weather or not our device should be NFC enabled to be able to use Android Pay in-app purchase of any other application

Tags: android-pay

I have gone through many links and studied many blogs regarding it.
I know that to be able to download Android Pay app our device must be NFC enabled. But can a user do in-app payment from a device who does not have android pay app installed on their phone?
Same as PayPal where we just enter our credential for doing payment.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need Android Pay if your app had a built-in feature to store a user's payment information. Just be aware of all of the additional side effects that come with keeping tracking of sensitive information (e.g. bank account info or a credit card number)

---

> Beginner's NFC Tutorial:
>   http://bluefletch.com/blog/android-nfc-reading-tags/